# Best Session Storage Middleware for Express + PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I'm looking for sessionstore for production app because I have error message:

> Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not designed for a
>   production environment, as it will leak memory, and will not scale
>   past a single process

My code:

```
var express              = require('express');
var ECT                  = require('ect');
var cookieParser         = require('cookie-parser');
var compress             = require('compression');
var session              = require('express-session');
var bodyParser           = require('body-parser');
var _                    = require('lodash');
var passport             = require('passport');
var expressValidator     = require('express-validator');
var connectAssets        = require('connect-assets');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: secrets.sessionSecret,
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

var app = module.exports = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port %d in %s mode',  app.get('port'), app.get('env'));
});

module.exports = app;
```

I don't know what is the best solution for my production app. I'm using sequelize as ORM with PostgreSQL. 
I will be very grateful with any opinion.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Though an answer has been accepted, I think a more elaborated answer is in order, so that people who actually want to use Express with PostgreSQL for consistent session storage can have a proper reference.

Express has the [session module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) to handle the sessions though it defaults to in-memory storage that is suitable for development stages but not for production

> Warning The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process, and is meant for debugging and developing.

So for PostgreSQL there is a dedicated simple connector called [connect pg simple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-pg-simple)

Once you import the connect-pg-simple you . need to pass it the session import like this:

```
const session = require('express-session')
const pgSession = require('connect-pg-simple')(session)
```

When you add the session as middleware you'll have to pass it its settings

```
app.use(session(sessionConfig))
```

and in your sessionConfig, this would be where you set all your session parameters you need to add a store option that would look like this (adding the full set of options though for the matter at hand just note the store option):

```
const sessionConfig = {
store: new pgSession({
    pool: sessionDBaccess,
    tableName: 'session'
}),
name: 'SID',
secret: randomString.generate({
    length: 14,
    charset: 'alphanumeric'
}),
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    sameSite: true,
    secure: false // ENABLE ONLY ON HTTPS
}}
```

The new instance of pgSesision takes two options, the pool which is the config setup to access the PostgreSQL DB and the table name.

The DB connection setting should look like this:

```
const sessionDBaccess = new sessionPool({
user: DB_USER,
password: DB_PASS,
host: DB_HOST,
port: DB_PORT,
database: DB_NAME})
```

Also note that the session pool must be initiated:

```
const sessionPool = require('pg').Pool
```

Answer (score 11):

I got it working with [connect-pg-simple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-pg-simple).

Create a session table with the provided table.sql, and pass in a connection string or an object.

Comment: The last release of `connect-pg-simple` was 7 months ago... Should I still use it for a new project?

Comment: @1valdis Looks like there was a new release in June 2018.

Answer (score -6):

If you have just to store session you can use [redis](http://redis.io/) or maybe mongoDB if you want persistence.

Comment: I don't wanna use another database.... It is bad idea store session in PostgreSQL ? I saw somewhere that store session in postgres is usually bad idea...

Comment: It depends. Session have limited lifetime so redis can handle this with TTL and automaticaly delete old session that are expired. But If you want to store and save all your sessions, PostGreSQL is maybe the good choice.

Comment: While the question was asking for postgres, redis is also a great option.